# Get LinkButton text using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, linkbutton

How can i get the text of LinkButton in .NET using javascript?

Tried .innerHTMl, .innerText, .value...all not working....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('lnk1').innerText
```

this should solve your problem, i tried it now and it works.
can you show me your code.

Answer (score 2):

for server side control use ClientID.

```
document.getElementById('<%= lnk1.ClientID %>').innerText
```

works for asp.net server side controls.